# React-native project not running in ios device (version 0.39.0)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Iam working on react-native app.
Previously my app is of version 0.25.0 but now i have upgraded the react native version of my appilication.

Now my app is not running on iOS device.
It showing like 
 'bundleURL must be non-nil when not implementing loadSourceForBridge'.

My AppDelegate.m file looks like:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
  NSLog(@"JSCodelocationh=%@",jsCodeLocation);
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Roger"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

In this my jsCodeLocation is returning null value.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this.

Comment: When you upgraded your project, did you also update the project files using `react-native update`?

Comment: yes I followed the procedure given in the docs of react native and i used `react-native upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Some of react native version upgrades require manual steps. [Read official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html) and [check with rn-diff](https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff).

Comment: Yes I checked but in that I have changed everything but still I am getting null in jscodelocation.

Comment: Tq I found the solution i have some internal errors that I couldn't see in the console so because of that my main.jsbundle is not created properly. After clearing all the errors my main.jsbundle is created properly and now getting my jscodelocation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
Adding `-lc++` in `Other Linker Flags` helped.

I also updated the code in AppDelegate to not use jsBundleURLForBundleRoot (it was used in the example project for react-native-navigation)

Check this: (npm 3 had the same issue)
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1

Comment: Tq I found the solution i have some internal errors that I couldn't see in the console so because of that my main.jsbundle is not created properly. After clearing all the errors my main.jsbundle is created properly and now getting my jscodelocation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me in solving my issue.
 I found the solution I have some internal errors that I couldn't see in the console so because of that my main.jsbundle is not created properly. After clearing all the errors my main.jsbundle is created properly and now getting my jscodelocation.